# Indexing with CloudWatch Logs Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

a question relevant to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70292465/how-can-i-get-a-cloudwatch-log-entry-that-happens-before-a-search-term/70671445?noredirect=1#comment124933346_70671445):

I'm trying to figure out how to capture records of a certain indexed difference when querying CWLI. Specifically, I need to find the record after each occurrence of an exception (yes, I know the below is an improper logging structure, however our hands are tied on this one):

[image]

Where the only two fields are Timestamp and Message. I can match all exceptions with the following query:

```
fields @message, (fields @message as a | filter \),(@message like "Exception for Aircraft id <StringArray>") as a
        | filter a = 1
```

How can we go about obtaining the next chronological message for each Exception?